# In Django, how do I take a file from views.py and set it as a JS array variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, file

I am creating a spelling test website. The spellings are in a file in my Django home folder (path 'home/quiz.txt') and I have written the necessary code in views.py to read the file from this location and set it as the variable "file" within the 'Quiz' view. 
However, when I go into the quiz.html or quiz.js, I do not know how to use this file in the actual code. What do I do?

views.py:

```py
class Quiz(TemplateView):
    template_name='quiz.html'
    file = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'home/quiz.txt'))
```

quiz.js:

```
function load(played, mistake, score){
  document.getElementById("clear").removeAttribute("hidden");
  document.getElementById("load").hidden=true;
  var x = file;
  var step;
  var spellList = document.getElementById("spellList");
  for (var xStep = 0; xStep < x.length; xStep++){
    if(x[xStep].match(mistake)){
      mistList.push(x[xStep]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you put it somewhere in STATIC_ROOT and use `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "SOME_PATH/quiz.txt" %}"></script>` ? If for some reason you need raw value in your template: `Quiz(TemplateView): ... def get_context_data(self, ...): context_data = super(...).get_context_data(...); context_data['quiz_contents'] = mark_safe(open(...).read()); return context_data`. [Docs on mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: I'm quite new to Django. This solution seems very plausible, however I am unsure as to what I would replace the '(...)' with in this example. Sorry to sound naive but  I am rather inexperienced. Thanks.
Edit: I am also confused as to the whereabouts of STATIC_ROOT. I tried looking in settings.py but it does not exist at least in the default file. Thanks again.

Comment: Again, I can add '<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "SOME_PATH/quiz.txt" %}"></script>' to my head tag as described but I do not know how to turn that into a manipulatable JS array. Thanks.